# Is it okay to delete a comment to re-post it with mistakes fixed if the edit grace period has ended?

Tags: discussion, comments

Sometimes I comment on an answer. After a little, I check the comment and it's wrong (usually because I posted it while working). But, for Murphy's law, five minutes passed.

So, if no one posted another comment (and this is true most of the time), I simply delete the comment and repost it corrected.

Some questions:

1. Is this a good practice?
2. Can't the edit countdown be a little relaxed?

Comment: 1) If no one posted another comment _or_ none of the comments following yours were a reply to you, I say sure, deleting and reposting the comment is probably the best course of action. 2) See [Comment editing grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155497/348196) on MSE.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine 1. ok, thank you 2. that thread is about the pencil icon. I don't want to hide the icon. I was thinking if the period you can edit the comment could be raised a little

Comment: You can read about the reasoning behind the 5-minutes grace period in Shog's answer (who was an SE employee at the time). That does not necessarily reflect my own opinion. I'm just trying to provide you with some information so you can take that into account if you decide to post a feature request about increasing the grace period, for example.

Comment: One thing to consider is that the new comment will trigger a new notification for the post owner and (if applicable) the user that you @-replied to. If this is essentially the same comment then people may get confused or annoyed that they are notified again.

Comment: @Marijn Well, this is why I was doubtful about the practice, and why I proposed an extension to the editing period.